# C ++, use a "typedef" of struct in a large "typedef" of struct

Tags: c++, struct, typedef

For my program I need to do something like this:

```
myObject.objectFunction(Process.MARKING);
```

To do this I thought of doing it like this:

file header:

```
typedef struct _process
{
   string process_name;
   string party_involved;
} process;

typedef struct _PROCESS
{
    process MARKING;
    MARKING.process_name = "...";
    MARKING.party_involved = "...";

    process COLORING;
    COLORING.process_name = "...";
    COLORING.party_involved = "...";
    ...
} PROCESS;
```

But I can't compile or correct the error.

I know I can use macros attached to namespaces, but I don't like having to use "::", and I also know that maybe this is not the best way to program.

I forgot to add that I would also like to make the elements of the struct constant larger i.e. not editable after compile and I also need to use the `typedef` of the smaller structure (process) outside the header file.

Can you tell me where I'm wrong, and/or a better way to do what I want to do?

Comment: You actually don't need to `typedef` your `struct`s at all - they are type defined automatically

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo, example with some code?

Comment: `typedef`ing is only necessary in C. In code purely used from C++ you'll want to avoid this, since this makes forward declarations more error prone and less readable (you'd need to use `struct _process;` instead of being able to use `struct process;` to forward declare the first struct). Note that any symbols starting with `_` followed by an uppercase letter are reserved for use by the compiler/the standard library; Especially in the case of `_PROCESS` this is risky.

Comment: @Titan Ok, I added examples. If that doesn't solve it, show us a [mre] so we can see how this function is defined etc: `myObject.objectFunction(Process.MARKING);`

Comment: @fabian, thanks I did not know, but in what risks will you go against if I use _PROCESS,  if I compile it will give me an error?

Comment: It's an instance of a [reserved identifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers). They're reserved so that the language and standard library implementations can use variable names for things without worrying that user code will also try to use those names. A lot of names that fall into the category of reserved identifiers are things that it's unlikely for the implementation to actually be trying to use... but `_PROCESS` is much more plausibly something that a compiler or library implementer would actually name a real variable.

Comment: Also for clarity maybe reconsider having two conceptually distinct structs whose names are identical except for capitalization. That just seems like a guarantee of future confusion.

Comment: @Titan Not necessarily. This could be a preprocessor macro that drastically changes the meaning of the code but happens to compile. It also could be some special symbol meant for use by the compiler to mark structs with specific properties. Even though code like this is likely result in a compiler error, there's absolutely no guarantee.

Comment: *I can't compile or correct the error* What error? Always post the exact error you faced. You could misinterpret the error, that could have nothing with the question title, and mislead SO users.

Answer (score 2):

You actually don't need to `typedef` your `struct`s at all - they are type defined automatically. You do however have a problem with initializing. In C++20, you can use designated initializers:

```cpp
#include <string>

struct process {
    std::string process_name;
    std::string party_involved;
};

struct PROCESS {
    process MARKING{
        .process_name = "...",
        .party_involved = "..."
    };
    // same for COLORING
};
```

And before C++20:

```cpp
struct process {
    std::string process_name;
    std::string party_involved;
};

struct PROCESS {
    process MARKING{
        "...",
        "..."
    };
    // ...
};
```

---

If you don't want any other object to be allowed to make changes to these member variables, make them `private` and provide `const&` accessors:

```
struct PROCESS {
    const process& getMarking() const { return MARKING; }

private:
    process MARKING{
        "...",
        "..."
    };
};
```

Now, `myObject.objectFunction(Process.getMarking());` can't change it and must either take the object *by value* or by *`const&`*:

```
struct Object{
    void objectFunction(const process& MARKING) {

    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, to make them constant I just need to add const before the process, right?

Comment: @Titan Yes, but that's often a mistake. Protect them by making them `private` instead. Otherwise you can't move them around or copy assign them

Comment: @Titan Added example for that too.